# Drupal adding custom variables to Mimemail template

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to add more variables than only the $body,$css,... to a *mimemail-message.tpl.php* template

```
preprocess_mimemail_message(&$variables)
```

lets me add custom vars, but what I want is to be able to pass the values when I'm calling *drupal_mail* to this template.

Thanks

Comment: There seems to be a need but no perfect solution. There is a patch suggested here : https://www.drupal.org/node/1568680

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively it can be done as follows:

```
template_preprocess_mimemail_message(&$variables) {
    $variables['test_var'] = 'some text';
}
```

And in template use it like this:

```
<?php print render($test_var); ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. Are you suggesting to modify this function in the mimemail module, or redefine it elsewhere, or is there a hook that would allow $variables to be modified any other way ?

Comment: You should use this hook in template.php and then display your custom variable in template file (.tpl.php).